# Delete path in Development Environment on Windows

Tags: windows

I have created regkey_path_bak.txt with this code

```
SET Key="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %Key% /v PATH`) DO Set CurrPath=%%B
ECHO %CurrPath%> regkey_path_bak.txt

C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Usuario\Manolo\Bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Usuario1\Manolo\Bin;C:\Soft\Bin
```

Now I wish split by semicolon

Then...delete all the lines with the name MANOLO

And join it all together in regkey_newpath_bak.txt (it should stay like this)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Soft\Bin
```

Comment: Why don’t you just use the GUI?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi... I need to add/remove the development environment and I can't find any correct solution to remove certain paths so I try to do it like this... but I didn't think it would be so difficult

Answer (score 0):

@HugoCar here is a batch file which will do what you want.

You can call :PARSE_PATH on any path string.  I put comments in certain places so you can understand what's going on

```
@echo off

SET REG_KEY="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
SET BAK_FILE=reg_key_bak.txt
SET SKIP_KW=manolo
SET NEW_FILE=reg_key_new.txt


FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %REG_KEY% /v PATH`) DO (
    call :PARSE_PATH "%%B"
)

REM you can call :PARSE_PATH with an existing path, or a string with a path
REM call :PARSE_PATH "%PATH%"

REM this removes the keyword    
findstr /i /v /c:"%SKIP_KW%" %BAK_FILE% > %NEW_FILE%

SET APATH=
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%I IN (%NEW_FILE%) DO (
    call :ADD_PATH "%%I"
)

echo %APATH%

REM remove first character, extra semi-colon
SET PATH=%APATH:~1%

REM unset everything
SET REG_KEY=
SET BAK_FILE=
SET SKIP_KW=
SET NEW_FILE=

exit /b 0


REM credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19009701 for this routine
:PARSE_PATH
setlocal

SET T=%~1

del %BAK_FILE% 2>nul

:LOOP

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%I IN ("%T%") DO (
    echo %%I>> %BAK_FILE%
    SET T=%%J
)

IF DEFINED T GOTO :LOOP

exit /b 0


REM this routine concats the path    
:ADD_PATH

SET APATH=%APATH%;%~1

exit /b 0
```

Comment: Hi...It almost works, just need to join reg_key_new.txt in one line to be able to send it to the registry with `set /p reg=<reg_key_new.txt
reg.exe ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%reg%" /f`

Comment: I don't think using the reg add would be the proper way to set the environment. You should just use the batch file up above to set up per console. You need to use winapi to notify all windows with a SendMessage or something if you're changing it thru the HKLM. it's something pretty complicated and not how you want it. Every terminal window you can use the batch file above to set the environment for every command prompt in your development environment. You can even launch executables from that prompt and it'll inherit the environment from this batch file.

Comment: I use this to put routes without repeating the routes even if I run it several times and I thought that removing them would be something similar but I see that it is not like that...at least I have learned something...thanks

Comment: `$targetDir=Get-Location
$oldPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
$oldPathArray=($oldPath) -split ';'
if(-Not($oldPathArray -Contains "$targetDir")) {
    $newPath = "$oldPath;$targetDir" -replace ';+', ';'
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",$newPath,"Machine")
    $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User"),[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") -join ";"
}
($env:Path).Replace(';',"`n")`